# Using the MVC pattern in games

Tags: game-design

I saw a lot oft tutorials about the mvc pattern, but always it was only a small example/Situation explained.
There was always only one model, one controller and one view.
But what if I have a lot oft models with complex logic, I cant put all the rendering code in one view and all the logic code in one controller.
How I split all in smaller pieces, because the models logic depends in each other(for example collision).
Know someone a good tutorial, or example game that explains this pattern in advanced games?